# Set Calendar default reminder to "none" for new appointments

Tags: htc-desire, calendar

When I input a new appointment on my HTC Desire S (running Android 2.3) the meeting has a 10 minutes reminder by default. I can manually set it to none for each appointment.

However, as I rarely want a reminder, how can I change the default to be None?

Thanks all

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Open the calendar app then select:

Menu->More->Settings->Default Reminder Time

and set to none.

Comment: This offers me options from 1 minute to 1 week but not none. If only it was that simple. The coder forgot to include none in the dropdown list.

Comment: Bummer. I'm on Android version 2.3.4 and on my device it has none right at the top above 1 minute.

Comment: I'm on Android 2.3.3 and HTC Sense 2.1 on my HTC Desire S (bought very recently unlocked from Amazon).